# Chrome Extension Dev: How to test onTabReplaced?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need to test code on [`webNavigation.onTabReplaced`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onTabReplaced).

> **onTabReplaced**
>
> Fired when the contents of the tab is replaced by a different (usually previously pre-rendered) tab.

Is there a page/script/method to activate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation, It mentions that onTabReplace event is fired when a Tab is replaced due to `prerendering` and `Instant`. Looking at the documentation of Chromium Prerender functionality at [link](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/prerender), looks like you can trigger a prerender using a `<link rel="prerender">` element.

Alternatively http://prerender-test.appspot.com/ is an example application making use of prerender. You can use this if all you want is to trigger the event.

Note: You need to enable the option "Use a prediction service to load pages more quickly" in chrome's advanced settings.